# Recommended way to install rubygems

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, rubygems, rvm, gem

There are server way to install rubygems

1. Using apt-get: apt-get install rubygems1.8
2. Using rvm: bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
3. Compile from source

Which one is better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the better method is to use the package manager. You can install, upgrade, remove,  dependencies are checked etc, with simple straightforward commands.